# how to avoid harmonic on intrrupt for proximity sensor in NodeMcu

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power, harmonics, nodemcu

i have 5v IR proximity sensor for measuring pulse output attached in NodeMCu
using intrrupt pin but it gets a random counter on the harmonic environment.

it is working fine in Normal situation what should i do now?

Comment: Hi and welcome ti the EE.SE. Please add a schematics and possibly a photo of the layout: otherwise other members will hardly understand what is your problem and, consequently, formulate suggestions on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You will really need to research if the pulse output from the sensor is actually generating spurious interrupts to the MCU. This could be in the form of noise, bad circuit design or upset from the environment. This type of study usually entails the use of an oscilloscope to evaluate signal integrity and make sure signalling is within specifications for proper operation.

A second instrument that may prove to be valuable in the research is a logic analyzer device that could help you correlate activity in your MCU software against signal pulses seen on the hardware interface.